# Use the same key for `, ~, esc

Tags: keyboard-layout

I am trying to use KBC Poker 3 keyboard which combines `,`~` and `<Esc>` as one key with Vim and wondering if it is possible to use the quick press of the escape key as char '`', and long press of escape key (longer than 500ms) as escape key.

Is it possible?

Comment: I don't think it's possible, but you can try to map two press as another one, that will simulate the workflow you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know there is no built-in support for mappings that change based on the time you hold the key.

But as the problematic key is <kbd>Esc</kbd>, you have some good alternatives:

1. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>, which works by default (as explained in [`:help key-codes`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/intro.txt.html#key-codes)):

   ```
   <Esc>       escape          CTRL-[   27 *escape* *<Esc>*
   ```
2. As <kbd>Esc</kbd> is a heavily used key in Vim, many people use mappings for it, such as <kbd>j</kbd><kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>j</kbd><kbd>k</kbd>, or <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>:

   - [Reaching up to hit the escape key sucks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397229/)
   - [Do you remap your Escape key?](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/2u051z/do_you_remap_your_escape_key/)
   - [Learn Vimscript the Hard Way - chapter 10](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/10.html)

If you choose to remap the <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> (as I did myself), you may find the [capslock plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-capslock) useful.